# Lightweight HTML viewer

Tags: software-recommendation, html

I'd like to write an HTML app for my own use that works offline. I'll edit my source code in Sublime Text 3. I don't have a lightweight app to render and show it.

I do know I can open HTML files in a Web browser, but opening an offline small HTML app in a Web browser such as Firefox seems too much. I'll consider using Safari too, but is there an even lighter HTML viewer out there?

Comment: Out of curiosity, why do you want such a light-weight app?

Comment: What features must the browser support? Does it need JavaScript? Must it be graphical or is a command line browser like [lynx](https://lynx.browser.org) suitable?

Answer (score 1):

You have not mentioned a platform explicitly in the question, but from the context it appears like you are looking for a macOS app.

For the scenario you described, I'd advise you to use the [Quick Look](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quick_Look) feature built into macOS. It lets you quickly preview a file's content in Finder. The default installation of macOS include support for common file types such as HTML (along with a host of other common file types such as PNG, JPG, MP3, PDF etc.)

To Quick Look your HTML file, simply click to select your file in a Finder window and press the <kbd>Spacebar</kbd> key. To dismiss the Quick Look preview, press the <kbd>Spacebar</kbd> key again or press the <kbd>Esc</kbd> key.

Quick Looking a HTML file will render the HTML preview of file instead of showing the HTML source.